# Effective Java Item #77 - Serialization of singleton objects - Why should I have to use readResolve?

Tags: java, serialization, singleton

[Effective Java](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336435020&sr=8-1) #77 states that we have to use `readResolve` to preserve the Singleton guarentee during serialization. They have used the example.

```
public class Elvis implements Serializable{
public static final Elvis INSTANCE = new Elvis();
private Elvis() { ... }
public void leaveTheBuilding() { ... }
```

and they suggest using

> If  the  Elvis  class  is  made  to 
>   implement  Serializable,  the 
>   following readResolve method suffices
>   to guarantee the singleton property:

```
// readResolve for instance control - you can do better!
private Object readResolve() {
// Return the one true Elvis and let the garbage collector
// take care of the Elvis impersonator.
return INSTANCE; }
```

> This method ignores
>   the deserialized object, returning the
>   distinguished Elvis instance that was
>   created when the class was
>   initialized.

- Now the question is does
  serialization loads the class again
  to have two instance of Elvis?
- If the    class is loaded only once
  then we    should be having only one
  instance of    Elvis since static
  fields are not    serialized and are
  not restored    during
  deserialization and
- From where does the other Elvis
  instance    comes which is made
  eligble for    garbage collection by
  readResolve    (prevented from
  escaping the    deserializtaion
  process). 
  Can this be    explained?

Answer (score 5):

- The class is only loaded once (unless you muck about with class loaders, but then the classes are actually different). Deserialisation of the above code does indeed create a new `Elvis`. You would need to use a serial proxy to avoid that.
- Whilst there are two `Elvis` instances, `Elvis.INSTANCE` only points to one.
- Deserialisation constructs an object without calling executing any constructors of serialisable classes (it does however execute the no-arg constructor of the most derived non-serialisable base class).

(And btw, you've not made your class `final`, so even a subclass can be deserialised. And, incidentally, your proposed `readResolve` method would not be called for a subclass as it is `private`.)

Comment: @Tom - according to the object serialization spec, the `readResolve` method can have any access modifier.  It can be `private`.

Comment: @Stephen I don't think that's true for a private method in a superclass

Comment: @Stephen C "This writeReplace method is invoked by serialization if the method exists and it would be accessible from a method defined within the class of the object being serialized." [from `java.io.Serializable`] So for a subclass, a private method would not be accessible (it's not going to follow rules for nested classes either...).

Comment: @Tom - "Deserialisation of the above code does indeed create a new Elvis" - Did you mean a new object of type Elvis is created and all the non-static and non-transient fields are populated with values from the deserialization process? In that case how do we have two values for the public static final filed INSTANCE?

Comment: @tutysara INSTANCE only points to one instance. One instance of `Elvis` is the original, and the other is the one you would normally expect from the deserialisation process, which has `readResolve` called on it (unless it is a subclass).

Comment: @Tom - I refer you to the "signature" of the `readMethod` "declaration" in section 3.7 of the spec.  It says `ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException;`

Comment: @Stephen C  "ObjectInputStream checks whether **the class of the object** defines the readResolve method." (my emphasis) Clarified in the API docs. I guess I could create a spec bug if the spec isn't sufficiently clear.

Comment: @Tom - I see what you were saying in your answer now.  (I was focussing on the fact that you were talking about a `private` method, where your real point was that it was in a subtype.)  But the spec is not crystal clear if a `readResolve` method would be called if it was declared in a superclass and *not* overridden in the actual class you are deserializing.  Whether it is *worth* creating a spec bug for that ... I don't know.  (I've submitted bugs like that in the past and nothing has been changed.  I've concluded it is a waste of time.)

Comment: @Stephen C If it is accessible in the superclass, say `protected` or some cases of "package private"/default access then `readResolve` still "works". / The non-spec docs of serialisation could do with a bit of an update - parts still talk about the 1.1 release as being in the future.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline In the first sentence you wrote "The class is only loaded once (unless you muck about with class loaders, but then the classes are actually different)" ...Shouldn't it be "*but then the `instances` are actually different*" or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: @Geek As far as the JVM is concerned, it's a completely different class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a proxy class inside your singleton class to hold all of your variables. Then you can have accessor functions [getProxyClass() & setProxyClass()]. Make the proxy class serializable, then when you go to serialize or deserialize use the proxy class and just use the accessor functions to get or set it. If you do it this way it cuts out a lot of the mess involved with the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

> - Now the question is does serialization loads the class again to have two instance of Elvis?

A new instance of Elvis is created (the impersonator), but the overloaded `readResolve` method ensures that it is not returned as part of the data structure returned by `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`.

The Elvis impersonator is (or soon becomes) unreachable, and is garbage collected.

> - If the class is loaded only once then we should be having only one instance of Elvis since static fields are not serialized and are not restored during deserialization and

Ideally yes.  In practice no.

> - From where does the other Elvis instance comes which is made eligible for garbage collection by readResolve (prevented from escaping the deserialization process). Can this be explained?

The deserialization process starts out by creating the 2nd Elvis (the impersonator), but the `readResolve` method ensures that nothing ever sees it.

To understand how and why that is the case, you need to understand the function that a `readResolve()` method plays in deserialization, as specified [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903).  Basically, when the `readResolve()` method returns `INSTANCE` it is saying, "wherever you were going to use the impersonator in the graph we are building, use the real Elvis instead".

Comment: @Stephen C The Elvis impersonator becomes unreachable, unless an adversary grabs a reference to it first.

Comment: @Stephen C - "The deserialization process starts out by creating the 2nd Elvis (the impersonator)" - Does it create another object and assign a new value for the static field INSTANCE? Static fields are not serialized and they are initialized when loading the class loads I guess.

Comment: @Tom - I thought that's what I said.

Comment: @tutysara - yes, a 2nd Elvis is created.  No, it does not assign the new Elvis to a static.  The normal object serialization mechanisms are not aware of statics, and Elvis's class-specific hooks (e.g. its `readResolve` method) don't assign to `INSTANCE`.

Comment: @Stephen C You said "is (or soon becomes) unreachable" and I say it ain't necessarily so. (Also `readResolve` is (not necessarily) overloaded or even overridden.)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - 1) I'm talking about the OP's code where `readResolve` *is* overridden in the Elvis class.  2) I also would treat the case where someone defines a subtype of Elvis as breaking the singleton pattern; i.e. "ChildClassOfElvis" is not singleton, and therefore multiple instances can exist.  Given that, how can an Elvis imposter become reachable?  Where can the "adversary" code get its hands on the imposter instance?

Comment: @Stephen C `private` methods cannot override (in the sense of override from the JLS). I don't understand how a subclass of a singleton can't break the singleton. Back references to the `Elvis` imposter is available until `readResolve` returns and the value processed.

Comment: A subclass of a singleton class (if you can create one) does not "inherit" its singleton-ness.  Subtypes of Elvis are only singleton if they are specifically implemented to be, complete with their own static `INSTANCE` and `getInstance()`.  (And that also involves providing a non-private constructor for Elvis ... which kind of breaks the singleton pattern.)  So what does this mean?  IMO, it means that Elvis imposters that are instances of some subclass of Elvis are conceptually *allowed* to exist ... as many times as you want.  They are Elvis impersonators rather than Elvis impostors :-).