# Serialization and Deserialization of Singleton Objects

Tags: java, serialization

If I implement the Singleton Design Pattern using the following implementation:

```
public class Singleton {  
    private static Singleton singleInstance = new Singleton();  
    private Singleton() {}  
    public static Singleton getSingleInstance() {  
        return singleInstance;  
    }  
}
```

then is there any need to write the readResolve method so that there are no multiple instances when we deserialize?This is because the instance variable is already static and static variables are not serialized.

Comment: **Always use an `enum` to implement the Singleton pattern**. Don't do what you're doing, it's full of (very non-obvious) flaws and loopholes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective Java Item #77 - Serialization of singleton objects - Why should I have to use readResolve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078785/effective-java-item-77-serialization-of-singleton-objects-why-should-i-have)

Comment: @BoristheSpider can u please explain how the serialization and deserialization is done for enums.Also if you could point out some loop holes,it would be of great help.

Comment: Enum serialization/deserialization is done for you -- it's a built-in mechanism, since enums are part of the language. At least one of the flaws in your implementation is that it isn't thread-safe. It's possible to end up with multiple singletons if you're unlucky with thread scheduling.